# How to dynamically generate mat-select inside ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material-6

I am using Angular 7 and Angular Material 6.4.1. I have a Form with a section for Employees. By default the Form has one empty employee info to be selected but more employees can be added so I will need to repeat (ngFor for employees array) the entire section. The section has multiples mat-select required with theirs formControl designated but when I set mat-select inside an ngFor and I click a button to add new employee and the entire section is duplicated ALL mat-select trigger event hasError and turn red. 
Employees array: otEmployees -- by default one empty 
I tried to create dynamic names for FormControls so each emp object has an array of formControls

```
<pre>
<div *ngFor="let emp of otEmployees; let i = index" id="bottomLine">

            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
              <div>
                <mat-label >Employee ID </mat-label>
                <mat-label >{{emp.employeeId}}</mat-label>
              </div>

              <div>
                <mat-form-field>
                  <mat-label>Employee Name</mat-label>
                  <mat-select [formControl]="emp.emploFormControls[0]" required [(ngModel)]="emp.employeeName">
                    <mat-option>Select --</mat-option>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let conseq of consequencesIfNotDone" [value]="conseq">`enter code here`
                      {{conseq.consequence1}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="selectedDivisionId < 1">Please choose a Division first</mat-error>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="emp.emploFormControls[0].hasError('required') && selectedDivisionId >= 1">Please choose an Employee
                    Name</mat-error>
                  <mat-hint>{{emp.emploFormControls[0].value?.sound}}</mat-hint>
                </mat-form-field>
              </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</pre>
```

Expected to duplicate the section with the mat-select and each one working independently. Current behavior is when duplicated all mat-select trigger hasError and turn red.

Comment: Use emp.emploFormControls[i] instead of emp.emploFormControls[0]

Comment: The comment by @khush might fix your issue, but you are not really using reactive forms to its full potential. Please have a look at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays , you should construct your ngFor loop according to the amount of formcontrols, that way you can also get rid of ([ngModel]) which shoudln't be used when using reactive forms, since the formcontrol keeps track of your model.

Comment: I agree with @Bastienverschaete

Comment: I can't use  emp.emploFormControls[i] because "emp" is the element in the array of nfFor and emploFormControls is a fix array that is created every time new employee is added and always has same amount of values in the same position